# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyJavaClasses/utility/MyCollection

Tags: java, directory, package, classpath, javac

I have a class named `MyCollection` in the directory

```
C:\Users\risha\OneDrive\RishavAgarwal\MyJavaClasses\utility\
```

inside the package - `MyJavaClasses.utility`

I have written a class named `P22_Generics1` in the directory

```
C:\Users\risha\OneDrive\Documents\Java Practice\
```

This class uses the above created class.

I successfully compiled it using the command

```
javac P22_Generics1.java -cp C:\Users\risha\OneDrive\RishavAgarwal
```

Now, when I try to run it using the command `java P22_Generics1`, this error occurs

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyJavaClasses/utility/MyCollection
    at P22_Generics1.main(P22_Generics1.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Java.utils.Collection
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

What can I do to execute it successfully?

The `P22_Generics1.java` looks like this

```
import MyJavaClasses.utility.MyCollection;

public class P22_Generics1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyCollection<Integer> collection = new MyCollection<>();
        collection.add(1);
        collection.add(4);
        collection.add(10);
        collection.add(5);
        System.out.println(collection);
        System.out.println(collection.get(3) + " " + collection.size());
    }
}
```

The `MyCollection.java` starts like this

```
package MyJavaClasses.utility;

import java.util.*;

/**
 * @author Rishav Agarwal
 * @param <T> This describes the Type parameter
 */
public class MyCollection<T> implements Cloneable {
    //...
}
```

Comment: what's in the run command line?

Comment: I run it using - java P22_Generics1

Comment: Sure, but I need to c what you put in command to run it. And please specify OS version.

Comment: run what? so far you haven't shown any code yet. are the classes in the same project? and why use a package name that already exists? by only making differences with upper/lowercases, you make it a hell to follow

Comment: We would need a real [mcve] here. But I am guessing that you source code is using an invalid package name, such as Java.utils.Collection - which should rather be java.util.Collections for example. But as said: you want us to spend our time to help you - so you please provide the information that we need to be able to help.

Comment: @GhostCat java.util.collections is an existing package in Java, creating a second one, with classes in it with the same name as that package might not lead to a desirable outcome.

Comment: Isn't Java.utils different from java.util? I have updated my question also!

Comment: @RishavAgarwal yes, it is, but at this point: only you know that. If ever someone else needs to maintain your code, this will no doubt confuse him. my guess, your class file goes looking for a class relative to it's position on your harddrive, and can't find it. not sure though

Comment: I have updated my package and class names which are clearly different from the pre-defined ones. Still the error persists! Please check my codes!

Comment: The error message is very clear: **your** class MyJavaClasses/utility/MyCollection (here written down using file system path separators) is **not** on your class path. That is all there is to this. The class path that you use for **running** your classes **must** also include the classes that you got from **compiling** your source code. That is all there is to this - this is a problem that has been asked and answered and documented zillions of times.